# Cannot GET error coming up when window.onload is used inside constructor

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

The website compiles fine without the code inside the constructor. However, I need the window.onload for the event listener to work properly. Any idea on how to fix/workaround this issue ?

```
export class SidenavigationComponent {
  public comp: NavMenuComponent;
  readonly ROOT_URL = 'https://localhost:44348/weatherforecast';
  axesclick() {
    console.log("Hi");
  }
  constructor() {
    this.axesclick = this.axesclick.bind(this);
    window.onload = function() {

      document.getElementById("Axes").addEventListener("click", this.axesclick);
    }
  }



}
```

Comment: What's the error? I don't get one when compiling your code with `class Thing { ... }` around it. Please provide minimal code to reproduce the issue?

Comment: My code doesn't compile with class x { } around it. The issue lies somewhere in the constructor that I cannot find a resolution for.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose without seeing the error message. You are using some Typescript syntax in the class. Is that intentional? Is your class extending another? If the error is from Typescript then it could be the `window` reference. try replace with `(window as any).onload`

Comment: Yes the typescript is intentional as this is a typescript file. The error is that when the code compiles, the chrome page opens but all previous working HTML is gone and only CANNOT GET is shows written on the top left

Answer (score 0):

you're expected to use a constructor inside a class

```
class Example {

 constructor() {
    this.axesclick = this.axesclick.bind(this);
    window.onload = function() {

      document.getElementById("Axes").addEventListener("click", this.axesclick);
    }
  }

}
```

and you're to call a class using the word new followed by the class name eg

```
const e = new Example()
```

Read more about JavaScript classes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Comment: It is within a class, check updated code (sorry for the misunderstanding).

Comment: when the code is run, the chrome page opens but the only thing it says is CANNOT GET at the top left

Comment: try adding a settimeout function before the calling  window.onload or try document.ready instead of window.onload